# Relationship between scalar function by vector differentiation and vector by scalar function differentiation

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, vector-analysis

The following question is regarding matrix calculus. Let $f$ be a function denoted by,
$$f = \sqrt{(a_1-a_2)^2+(a_2-a_3)^2+(a_1-a_3)^2+3(a_4^2+a_5^2+a_6^2)}$$
and $\pmb A$ be a vector defined by,
$$ \pmb A = (a_1 \space a_2 \space a_3 \space ...a_6)^T$$
$\frac{d f}{d\pmb A}$ can be readily computed by evaluating the following,
$$\frac{d f}{d\pmb A} = (\frac{df}{da_1} \space \frac{df}{da_2} \space \frac{df}{da_3} \space ...\frac{df}{da_6})$$
But what I require is an expression for / need to evaluate is $\frac{d\pmb A}{df}$.
If $\frac{d\pmb A}{df}$ is,
$$\frac{d\pmb A}{df} = (\frac{da_1}{df} \space \frac{da_2}{df} \space \frac{da_3}{df} \space ...\frac{da_6}{df})^T$$
does the following relationship (Inverse function theorem like relationship) hold true for $\frac{d\pmb A}{df}$?
$$\frac{d\pmb A}{df} = (\frac{1}{{df} \over {da_1}} \space \frac{1}{{df} \over {da_2}}  \space \frac{1}{{df} \over {da_3}}  \space ...\frac{1}{{df} \over {da_6}})^T$$
(Here, $\frac{df}{da_i} \neq 0 $ for $i = 1, 2, ..., 6$ and $f$ is continuously differentiable in the interval of interest).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your assumption should hold.  When differentiating a matrix by a scalar quantity, we don't need to worry about how differentiation will affect the dimensionality of our result.  In general, given a matrix $X$ we have that

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left [ \begin{array}{cccc}
x_{11} & x_{12} & \ldots & x_{1n} \\
x_{21} & x_{22} & \ldots & x_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
x_{m1} & x_{m2} & \ldots & x_{mn} \\
\end{array} \right ] \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{cccc}
\frac{dx_{11}}{dt} & \frac{dx_{12}}{dt} & \ldots &\frac{dx_{1n}}{dt} \\
\frac{dx_{21}}{dt} & \frac{dx_{22}}{dt} & \ldots &\frac{dx_{2n}}{dt} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{dx_{m1}}{dt} & \frac{dx_{m2}}{dt} & \ldots &\frac{dx_{mn}}{dt} \\
\end{array} \right ].
$$

In the case you have in your prompt, you would simply be taking derivatives $\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial f}$, which can be found implicitly using single variable calculus.